# Prefect how to avoid rerunning a task

Tags: python, workflow, airflow, etl, prefect

In Prefect, suppose I have some pipeline which runs f(date) for every date in a list, and saves it to a file. This is a pretty common ETL operation. In airflow, if I run this once, it will backfill for all historical dates. If I run it again, it will know that the task has been run, and only run any new tasks that have appeared (ie latest date).

In Prefect, to my knowledge, it will run the entire pipeline every day, even if 99% of the tasks were completed the day before. What are some solutions to dealing with this, without switching to Prefect Cloud? Do you just do something like make every task cache it's completion in redis before exiting?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Prefect has many first-class ways of handling caching, depending on how much control you want. For every task, you can specify whether results should be cached, how long they should be cached, and how the cache should be invalidated (age, different inputs to the task, flow parameter values, etc.).

The simplest way to cache a task is to use [targets](https://docs.prefect.io/core/idioms/targets.html#using-result-targets-for-efficient-caching), which lets you specify that the task has a templatable side effect (usually a file in local or Cloud storage, but could be e.g. a database entry, redis key, or anything else). Before the task is run, it checks if the side effect exists and if it does, skips the run.

For example, this task will write its result to a local file automatically templated with the task name and the current date:

```py
@task(result=LocalResult(), target="{task_name}-{today}")
def get_data():
    return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

As long as a matching file exists, the task won't re-run. Because `{today}` is part of the target name, that will implicitly cache the task's value for one day. You could also use a parameter in the template, like the backfill date, to replicate Airflow's behavior.

For more control, you can use Prefect's [full cache mechanism](https://docs.prefect.io/core/concepts/persistence.html#output-caching) by setting `cache_for`, `cache_validator`, and `cache_key` on any task. If set, the task will finish in a `Cached` state instead of a `Success` state. When paired with a proper orchestration backend like Prefect Server or Prefect Cloud, the `Cached` state can be queried by future runs of the same task (or any task with the same `cache_key`). That future task will return the `Cached` state as its own result.

Comment: what if second time the task is called before the first one is complete (i.e. cache is not set yet)?